# Laravel set slug correctly

Tags: php, laravel

In my post model I have this:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

When I go to page post my link is: `http://example.com/post/there-a-slug`

How I want do link like this: `http://example.com/post/id_post/there-a-slug`

In my routes:

```
Route::get('/post/{post}', 'PostController@show')->name('showpost');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Route will be something like below:

`Route::get('/post/{id}/{slug?}', 'PostController@show')->name('showpost');`

And also you have to update your `show` function on your `PostController`

```
public function show(Request $request,$id,$slug=null)
{
  //now you can find your post with id
  $post=Post::findOrFail($id);
  //your code goes here
}
```